# How to decode an image once render multiple time

Tags: android, opengl-es, multiviews

An image is decoded once, and I need to render the surface associated with decoder multiple time to different surfaceTexture, then display them on screen at same time, how could I realize this? what should I created multiple time? SurfaceTexture? Surface? native window and some other objects related to OpemGL render?

Comment: use multiple WindowSurface object connect to the different surface of each view and share a GLContext object + SurfaceTexture, te same as https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java